# Two Page Login with Spring Security 3.2.x

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

We are brand new to Java, Spring, and Spring Security, but not new to development. We've been able to create a Spring Security-based Thymeleaf login page that uses a JNDI datasource to connect to our SQL Server database using BCrypt encrypted passwords. All of that is working without a hitch. However, the client wants a two-stage login. The first page requests a company ID that then loads a login page with specific graphics and text for that company, which allows the user to know that they are not logging into a phishing site. That login page would then request the user name and password.

We have searched extensively on here and the web as a whole and have not found a solid method for doing this. We believe that we may to have to create a custom `UserDetailsService` and `AuthenticationManager`, but still can't see how to implement it so that:

1. User cannot bypass first login screen and go straight to second screen
2. SpringSecurity is in control of both pages

We saw one suggestion about using Spring WebFlow with Spring Security, but without some starting point, have no idea how WebFlow works or applies to this scenario. This site helped us greatly in getting to this stage, but now we are stymied. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To answer part of your question, you usually need to create a `UserDetailsService` when integrating with a custom backend (not plain LDAP or SS-managed JDBC). It's basically just a facade in front of your authentication backend for Spring Security to use, and you just implement the single-method interface by using the `username` parameter to perform whatever lookup is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your DB stores ALL users from all companies in one single table. You do not separate the users from different companies to different tables. If this is the case, you need only one single login page. The thing is, that you have a first page that the user enters his company ID, and you use this ID to get the JPGs and logos and put them on the login page.

note that **this has no security profit.** because anyone can enter other's company ID and get logos of different company, and yet can try to login. IS this your requirement?

the thing is that your login page needs to show logos and JPGs according to the previous page, where the company ID was entered. If none was given, show an error instead. So your login page needs to have some logic, and input - if you make it a JSP it is very easy to implement....

HTH

Comment: This is basically what we ended up doing. Currently the initial login screen requests the clientID and retrieves their information from the database. We overload the user login page to include clientID as part of their login. Taking a note from Willie Wheeler's answer, we have recommended incorporating a CAPTCHA on the initial login page that get's the client's ID if their IP address is unknown to the system for that client. We apologize for the delay in marking this as answered, we've been neck deep in this project ever since posting.

Comment: thanks! Hope that is works well :-) BTW - im curious: did you implement all other flows, such as 'create account', 'forgot password', etc?

Comment: Yes. The new user account isn't in place yet, but all of the forgot password/username/client ID, reset password, password rules, etc is in place.

Comment: pity there is no "spring" project for that :-) i wrote some generic code for these flows... in github. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There should be *three* pages here:

1. Initial login page with a form that asks for your username, but not your password.
2. You didn't mention this one, but I'd check whether the client computer is recognized, and if not, then challenge the user with either a CAPTCHA or else a security question. Otherwise the phishing site can simply use the tendered username to query the real site for the security image, which defeats the purpose of having a security image. (A security question is probably better here since with a CAPTCHA the attacker could have humans sitting there answering the CAPTCHAs to get at the security images. Depends how paranoid you want to be.)
3. A page after that that displays the security image and asks for the password.

I don't see this short, linear flow being sufficiently complex to warrant using Spring Web Flow.

I would just use straight Spring Web MVC for steps 1 and 2. I wouldn't use Spring Security for the initial login form, because Spring Security's login form expects a password and a login processing URL. Similarly, Spring Security doesn't provide special support for CAPTCHAs or security questions, so you can just use Spring Web MVC once again.

You can handle step 3 using Spring Security, since now you have a username and a password. The form login page should display the security image, and it should include the user-provided username as a hidden form field to make Spring Security happy when the user submits the login form. The only way to get to step 3 is to have a successful `POST` submission on step 1 (and 2 if applicable).

Comment: good answer, but it seems as you have changed his requirements: he wants the first page to force the user to enter the organization ID, and not his username...

Comment: Hm, you're right. Though I guess I'm not seeing how loading company graphics on the second page prevents phishing, since the phishing sites can just use the same graphics. My answer explains how one might implement a two-phase login like financial sites have.

Comment: I guess that's the same point you make in your response. I agree with you.